# Create a new column that take previous year's rate if current month is January

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I want to create a new column that takes previous year's rates if the current month is January else use current rates.

```
| Date       |  Sales   | Rates | Month  |  Year   |
|:-----------|---------:|:-----:|-------:|:-------:|
| 1/1/2017   |   10000  |  8.0  |   1    |  2017   |
| 1/1/2018   |   20000  |  8.2  |   1    |  2018   |
| 2/1/2018   |   15000  |  8.2  |   2    |  2018   |
| 1/1/2019   |   11000  |  8.5  |   1    |  2019   |
| 3/1/2019   |   18000  |  8.5  |   3    |  2019   |
| 1/3/2020   |   22000  |  9.0  |   1    |  2020   |
```

Here the new column should have previous years rates if the month is January.

I tried this but failed to get results.

```
if [Year] > 2017 and [Month] = 1 then [Rates] = [Rates] and [Year] = 2018 else [Rates]
```

Comment: why compare the year?  `If [month] = 1 then [year] = [year]-1` then use that year to determine the rate?  that way you can deal with all years

Comment: I am new to Power Query. So please explain how its going to change rates. Once we define if condition for If [Month] = 1 then we need to map this update with rates. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a calculated column:

[image]

```
New Rates =
VAR prevYear = 'Table'[Year] - 1
VAR ratePreviousYear =
    MAXX ( FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Year] = prevYear ), 'Table'[Rates] )
RETURN
    IF (
        'Table'[Month] > 1
            || ISBLANK ( ratePreviousYear ),
        'Table'[Rates],
        ratePreviousYear
    )
```